# Django app not recognized when inside another module

Tags: python, django

I have a project with a structure like this:

```
my-django-project/
     venv/
     .gitignore
     README.md
     my_django_project/
          db.sqlite3
          manage.py
          my_django_project/
               settings.py
          my_first_app/
               __init__.py
               inside_app/
                    __init__.py
                    apps.py
                    serializers.py
                    models.py
                    views.py
                    ...
```

In `settings.py` i loaded the app like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_first_app.inside_app',
]
```

Running `py manage.py runserver` gives the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\\Documents\GitHub\tin_api_v2_test\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 246, in create      
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'inside_app'. Check that 'my_first_app.inside_app.apps.InsideAppConfig.name' is correct.
```

However, it works fine when I don't use the Virtualenv. I've also tried putting the venv inside the django project folder to see if that would change anything but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it..
In `apps.py` of `inside_app` i had to change from:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class InsideAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'inside_app'
```

to

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class InsideAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_first_app.inside_app'
```